# Where is the Installation Media needed to perform a Repair on a SQL Server 2016 installation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server 2016 Express installation that I recently performed an edition upgrade on to make it a Standard edition so that I could have access to SQL Agent. After performing the edition upgrade I noticed that SQL Agent would not start as the Log On account was not properly configured. I found a recommendation online to run the Repair action from the SQL Server Installation Center. When I try to do this it asks me to browse for the folder that contains the 2016 Installation Media. What folder is it looking for? I don't want to re-download and re-install on a working, production instance, I just want to run the repair.

NOTE: I have since gotten SQL Agent to work by specifying a domain admin service account for the Log On, I just would like to know how to be able to run Repair on the instance in case I need it in the future.

[image: Repair Installation]

Comment: I don't understand why my question deserves a downvote. The installation media does not present the option to repair, but the SQL Server Installation Center that was placed into the start menu from the install DOES have the option, yet won't work. I am trying to find a solution to run the repair action on a SQL Server Express installation that was upgraded to standard using the edition upgrade feature.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I did not. I ended up manually configuring the Log On account to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repairing is an option of the original installer. That's the installation media that it's referring to, typically an `*.iso` file that represents the installer. You should be able to utilize the original installer you used to repair the installation as well.

Comment: I've tried that. The installer goes right into the installation steps with no option to choose repair.

Comment: @DavidChristian I don't follow, your screenshot shows the repair option. After you click that and then choose your installation media, it'll go through a series of steps that *look similar to an installation* but actually do a repair.

Comment: The screenshot is of the SQL Server Installation Center which is in my start menu as part of the initial installation. I used this to perform the Edition Upgrade from Express to Standard. When I try to run "Repair" from this tool, it asks me for a folder with the installation media. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: @DavidChristian Right, as I already said in my last comment, after selecting "Repair", select the folder where the `*.iso` lives for your installer. Then it'll start the "Repair" steps which look similar to the installation steps.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but there is no .iso. The installation media I used is an exe SQLServer2016SP2-KB4052908-x64-ENU.exe. I tried selecting the folder where this .exe is found, but that does not work. Perhaps if I had an .iso, I could mount the .iso and try pointing it to that folder, but so far I have been unable to locate an .iso version of the installer.

Comment: @DavidChristian Ah gotcha, I assumed the edition upgrade was through an `*.iso`. Unfortunately I'm not sure how you should proceed then. You could try the `*.iso` for another edition of the same version of SQL Server (e.g. the evaluation edition you can download freely from Microsoft) and *maybe* the repair will work fine, but I don't have enough experience trying that to say if it could result in any other issues. I'd say if you were to try it, definitely don't do it with a production server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the media location in options.  You should be able to use a STD edition of the media to do the repair.  If you have an ISO, you must mount it first.  Either that or extract the contents to a local folder and use that.

The issue with the virtual account is common in our shop in the standard OU for workstations.  A repair will restore the rights to log on as a service to the virtual account.  Then a short time later group policy will remove the permission again.  It's not uncommon for developers to use the network service account instead.

I've use repair to restore permissions on a server that was moved to the wrong OU temporarily.  It was moved back, but policy had already did its thing.  The repair worked.

Using a service account for permission that should be on virtual accounts instead seems to work.  I don't like it.  The documentation does not say this is okay.  For example, in an auto reboot after an agent crash does the service need to start by using the virtual account before it can use permissions of the the service account?  (I have no idea how this works internally.  In steady state, all the permission are there, no matter the source.)